# Python - Pass a variable to a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im curently learning Python (2.7) using the excellent tutorials from http://www.learnpythonthehardway.org/

I am trying to make a small text input game to improve my skills, as part of this I am trying to add a Health meter to the main character. I am also adding combat which will reduce their health.

The below code is designed to set the players health to 100 at the start of each game, it does this by executing another function "player_health" in a class called "Set_Health"

```
class Health():

    def store_health(self):

        d = Set_Health()
        d.player_health()
        local_health = d.player_health()

        print "Your health is at", local_health, "%"
        return local_health
```

When the below "punch_received" function is executed, the players health is reduced by 10

```
class Combat():

    def punch_received(self):

        punch = 10

        x = Health()
        x.store_health()
        combat_health = x.store_health()

        combat_health = combat_health - punch
        print "You have been punched, your health is", combat_health, "%"
```

So far so good. It may not be perfect or the best methodology but it works as a base to learn from.

My issue is that i do not know how to how to return/send the value of "combat_health" to another variable e.g. "current_hero_health" that is in another function.

```
class Hero_Health():

    def current_hero_health(self):

        # I want to store a running total of the heros health in here
```

Any help with this is very much appreciated. Thanks Deepend

Comment: Although you wrote you know that it "may not be perfect or the best methodology", I would suggest to design your classes a bit more naturally. So your Hero should be an instance of the class `Hero` with the method(s) "Punch"… and properties like "Health" etc. and each "Fight" should be an instance of "Combat". Doing so will help you naturally find the best way to design your variable flows. You obviously did not catch the usage of Object Oriented Programming yet, since you're trying to mimic functional programming ;-)

Comment: Thanks septi, i ended up rebuilding the project as you suggested as every change i made just created new errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make `current_hero_health` an attribute of your `Hero_Health`.

```
class Hero_Health():

    def __init__(self, current_h):
        self.current_hero_health = current_h

    def current_hero_health(self):
        self.current_hero_health = 3 ; # this is stored total of hero health
```

You can access member from any method of the class, with `self.current_hero_health`, and it is stores a global count for an object of this class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add more parameters to the function. The first argument to functions defined in a class (as opposed to `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`) is the object itself, and all the parameters to the function appear after that:

```
def current_hero_health(self, value):
    self.health = value

MyHealthObject.current_hero_health(5)
```